# Add sql login issue on windows server 2008 with SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, smo

Using SMO I've tried to add an SQL SERVER login installed in windows 7 with this code and it worked well, but it didn't  work on windows server 2008.

- Am I missing something ?

  ```
      Login _Login;
      string _UserID ;
      string _User;
      string _Password;

  try
          {
              _Login = new Login(wm._Server, _UserID);
              _Login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
              _Login.Create(_Password);
              _Login.AddToRole("sysadmin");
          }
          catch (Exception ex1)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message);
          }
  ```

Comment: Sorry, I've got this error message : Create failed for Login 'LoginName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the password was not complex enough (win 2k8 policy). I have found it in the InnerException property.